# AutoCompletetextview with dynamic array list

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi im just started to learn android Studio and i wanted to have a `AutoCompletetextView` and a Button that adds user input if the user input wasnt listed in the array list.my `AutoCompleteTextView` completely works but i cant get through the onClick listener.any help would be appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        actv = findViewById(R.id.actv);
        actv.setThreshold(1);

        String[] color = {"blue", "brown", "black", "red", "green", "gray", "violet", "white", "orange"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, color);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });




    }
}
```

and xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Add"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: is onClick() method being called?

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you want on your button click?

Comment: i want the button check if the user input not listed just adds it to the list. for example user types red and red is not listed so the button adds it and next time if i just type r and it autocompletes it to red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    String[] color = {"blue", "brown", "black", "red", "green", "gray", "violet", "white", "orange"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, color);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

with

```
final List<String> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
colorList.add("blue");
colorList.add("green");

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, colorList);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String text = actv.getText().toString();
       int size = colorList.size();
        boolean exists = false;
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
           if(colorList.get(i).equals(text)){
              exists = true;
           } 
       }
       if(exists==false){
         colorList.add(text);
         ArrayAdapter newAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, colorList);
         actv.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it gives me "Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter..."   on the second ArrayAdapter

Comment: Ho....sorry....Change actv.setAdapter(adapter); to actv.setAdapter(newAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use **ArrayList** instead of `String[]`

Here is code how we can add item into ArrayList when button is Clicked

```
ArrayList<String> color1 = new ArrayList<>();
color1.add("blue");
color1.add("brown");
color1.add("black");
color1.add("red");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, color1);
actv.setThreshold(1);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         String s = String.valueOf(actv.getText());
         adapter.add(s); //Add Item in Adapter
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help you..Enjoy Coding! @khashayarKazemi